# Gap in HStack between two views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to have two views in an HStack using SwiftUI. However, I keep getting a gap between the two views.
The problem occurs in both portrait and landscape layouts.

my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in
            HStack {
                GeometryReader { g in
                    HStack {
                        VStack {
                            Text("View One")
                        }
                        .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.5, height: g.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.blue)

                        VStack {
                            Text("View Two")
                        }
                        .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.5, height: g.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }         
        }    
    }
}
```

[image: The gap is between the View One and View Two]

Comment: Try setting the spacing by using `HStack(spacing: )`

Comment: Have you tried to add spacing, like so: `HStack(spacing: 0)`?
EDIT: @Malik you were faster ;-)

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you try to make the size (`width`) of both `VStack`s slightly smaller?

Comment: It worked with (Spacing: 0) put the answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Malik post the answer so I can accept it

Comment: @FadyE I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The spacing can be setup at the time of initialising

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: It makes complete sense -- but for a while I was trying to modify the gaps between other stacks.  Argh-- great find here!